# Error in DropdownButton. There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value,

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdownbutton, flutter-dropdownbutton

I have created the DropdownBotton inside the ListView and i have a list of values which needs to be displayed in the DropdownMenuItem.

I have 2 questions with respect to DropdownBotton,

1. How to set the default value in the DropdownButton for my scenario.
2. (console error)

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: $ 5.50 Pineapple Jack (S). 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 915 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

Below is my code:

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {

    List<String> selectedItemValue = <String>[
    ("\$${snapshot.data![index].price} ${snapshot.data![index].productType.type1}"),
    ("\$${snapshot.data![index].price} ${snapshot.data![index].productType.type2}"),
    ("\$${snapshot.data![index].price} ${snapshot.data![index].productType.type3}")];
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropdownValue,
                  items: selectedItemValue.map((dropValue) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: dropValue,
                              child: Text(dropValue),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged:
                              (newDropdownValue) {
                            setState(() {
                              dropdownValue =
                              newDropdownValue!;
                              print(
                                  'dropdown: $dropdownValue');
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                ),
        ],
    );
  }
),
```

Please someone help me on this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the value that you are passing in dropdownValue matches any of your dropdown options?

Comment: Yes i am getting the required values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropdownButton`'s value should be unique among `DropdownMenuItem`' values and There must be one `DropDownMenuItem` in items which exactly matches the current value of the `DropDownButton`.
in your case you are not setting `DropdownButton`s value from  `selectedItemValue`. Therefore answers for your questions are,

1. set initial value of the `DropdownButton` which you want's to be your default value from `selectedItemValue`.
2. to avoid the error, move your `DropdownButton` to separate `StatefullWidget` (`CustomDropdownButton` in this case.). change your code as follows.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {

    List<String> selectedItemValue = <String>[
    ("\$${snapshot.data![index].price} ${snapshot.data![index].productType.type1}"),
    ("\$${snapshot.data![index].price} ${snapshot.data![index].productType.type2}"),
    ("\$${snapshot.data![index].price} ${snapshot.data![index].productType.type3}")];

final defaultValue = selectedItemValue[1];

        return CustomDropdownButton(defaultValue:defaultValue, values: selectedItemValue, onItemSelected: (value) {print("Selected Item : $value");});
      }
    ),
```

`CustomDropdownButton` class

```dart
class CustomDropdownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDropdownMenu(
      {Key? key,
      required this.defaultValue,
      required this.values,
      required this.onItemSelected})
      : super(key: key);
  final dynamic Function(String? selectedValue) onItemSelected;
  final String defaultValue;
  final List<String> values;
  @override
  _CustomDropdownMenuState createState() => _CustomDropdownMenuState();
}

class _CustomDropdownMenuState extends State<CustomDropdownMenu> {
  late String dropdownValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dropdownValue = widget.defaultValue;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              items: widget.values.map((dropValue) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: dropValue,
                  child: Text(dropValue),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newDropdownValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newDropdownValue!;
                });
                widget.onItemSelected(newDropdownValue);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is giving your dropdown a `value` that might be replicated in your list. Meaning that your list of strings might have multiple items with the same String. To solve this you need to give the `value` param a unique value. In this case you can use the array's index as in the code below.

I tried to replicate your code with dummy lists so I can run it and test it.

```dart
class _StarterPageState extends State<StarterPage> {
  Map<int, int?> dropdownValues = {};

  final List<String> _list = [
    'List Item 1',
    'List Item 2',
    'List Item 3',
    'List Item 4',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: _list.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, parentListIndex) {
          List<String> selectedItemValues = <String>[
            'Dropdown Item 1',
            'Dropdown Item 2',
            'Dropdown Item 3',
            'Dropdown Item 4',
          ];

          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton<int>(
                    hint: const Text('Select Item'), // Shown when value is null
                    // ?? (selectedItemValues.isNotEmpty ? 0 : null) => this adds a default value if the value is null
                    value: dropdownValues[parentListIndex] ?? (selectedItemValues.isNotEmpty ? 0 : null),
                    items: List.generate(
                      selectedItemValues.length,
                      (i) => DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                        value: i,
                        child: Text(selectedItemValues[i]),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (newDropdownValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValues[parentListIndex] = newDropdownValue!;
                        print('dropdown: ${dropdownValues[parentListIndex]}');
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Moreover, since you have multiple dropdowns, you need to separate your dropdown values, so this is why I created a map that has the following structure:

```dart
{
   <parentListIndex>: <dropdownValueIndex>,
   <parentListIndex>: <dropdownValueIndex>,
  //...
}
```

You can add a `hint` param to your `DropdownButton` widget like so:

```dart
DropdownButton<int>(
   hint: const Text('Select Item'),
   value: dropdownValueIndex,
   //...
)
```

See live demo in this DartPad
https://dartpad.dev/?id=08ace6b8f73cff0216673dcf9def433d

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful.